# Novo-Map plugin causing WordPress admin panel sessions to expire

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have the [Novo-Map plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/novo-map/) installed on my client's website that is running WordPress 5.3. The plugin is used to display markers assigned to posts on a Google Map. The plugin's functionality is working correctly, but there seems to be some conflicts with user session management in WordPress 5.3+. With the plugin active, the sessions expire every couple of minutes in the WordPress admin panel, forcing admin users to log back into the panel. The expiration can happen while editing a post, working in the Settings area, or anywhere else in the admin panel (areas unrelated to Novo-Map).

I have tested the session expiry in Brave, Chrome, and Firefox. All of these browsers are experiencing the same issues. No JavaScript errors are displayed in the console.

The plugin has not been updated for version 5.3, so I am assuming this may be the culprit, though it seems strange that the sessions expire when not interacting with the plugin.

I have tested this using MAMP Pro on localhost and remotely on a server with similar specs.

Does anyone have some insight into this issue? Cheers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because does not contain a proper code-related question, as required on this site. This is not a place to vaguely ask if anyone had any “insights”. Your options are to either delve into the code and try to find where things go wrong, or ask the plugin developer for support.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Insert on u wp_footer

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please, to make it a more constructive answer, elaborate more on your solution. Explain what you are doing and how it fits into the poster's question.